# How do I alternate domains for sending emails for my app running on Heroku with Sengrid Add-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, dns, sendgrid

So we are running a rails app on Heroku with the Sengrid add-on (free plan so no whitelabeling) (let's call it magicapp) and in our action mailer we always set the from field to be "noreply@magicapp.com". We have seen some of our email go to spam and someone suggested to us to try to alternate our email domain to improve deliverability.

So my questions are as follows:

1. What verification and checking goes on at the receiver side to verify that the email really is sent from "magicapp" and not just someone pretending to be magicapp?
2. Right now, when we send an email from "noreply@magicapp.com" the email says it's from "noreply@magicapp.com via sendgrid.me" so when receiver clients are doing spam checking, do they use my "magicapp.com" domain for reputation or the "sengrid" domain?
3. If it does use the "magicapp.com" domain, could I just set my from field in my action mailer to be a different domain such as "magicapp-mail.com"? Are there any potential issues to this or additional things to set up, like DNS etc? If I do this, will the receiver use the reputation of the magicapp-mail domain instead of magicapp then?

Any answers or information would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure setting sendgrid's **DKIM** and **SPF** records properly will save your emails from being sent to spam. At least that's what worked in my app I was working on and emails ended in inbox, unless users hit **Mark as spam** instead of **unsubscribe**.

**DKIM**

DKIM stands for DomainKeys Identified Mail which was designed to help ISPs prevent malicious email senders by validating email from specific domains.

What a basic DKIM record should look like:

```
smtpapi._domainkey.yourdomain.com.  |  TXT or CNAME  |  value
smtpapi._domainkey.subdomain.yourdomain.com.  |  TXT or CNAME  |  value

TXT value: k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDPtW5iwpXVPiH5FzJ7Nrl8USzuY9zqqzjE0D1r04xDN6qwziDnmgcFNNfMewVKN2D1O+2J9N14hRprzByFwfQW76yojh54Xu3uSbQ3JP0A7k8o8GutRF8zbFUA8n0ZH2y0cIEjMliXY4W4LwPA7m4q0ObmvSjhd63O9d8z1XkUBwIDAQAB

CNAME value: dkim.sendgrid.net
```

docs: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/dkim.html

**SPF**

Sender Policy Framework (SPF) is an email authentication standard developed by AOL that compares the email sender’s actual IP address to a list of IP addresses authorized to send mail from that domain. The IP list is published in the domain’s DNS record.

The DNS record should look like this:

```
yourdomain.com.  |  TXT  |  v=spf1 a mx include:sendgrid.net ~all
```

docs: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/spf.html

Comment: Thanks for the info! DKIM helps even if we don't use whitelabeling right? Also, I'm a little confused because in the documentation it says sendgrid automatically enables DKIM for all email, and it seems like I only need to use the custom DKIM if I'm using whitelabeling is that right?

Comment: Sorry, in our case we had a silver account, so I was wrong, anyway, if you are on a free plan you should expect to have emails in spam, cause your sender is not trusted by mail client (gmail, yahoo...), only after you have at least a silver plan you can start whitelabeling process.

https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200548228-All-You-Need-to-Know-About-Whitelabeling and then your domain `magicapp.com` will be recognized and trusted so you don't need to find workarounds.

Comment: "Whitelabeling is a process that ... can lead to a better sending reputation and more consistent inbox delivery" - basically they say that with a free plan, your emails might get into inbox sometime as well as in spam, but I believe this is not in any way related with what you have in `from:` attribute in your app. You could have whatever you want there, the sender will still be blablablba.sendgrid.com (like with mandrill `no-reply@aaastriping.com via mail132-13.atl151.mandrillapp.com `), and ony after whitelabeling you'll be able to use your own domain. That's how I see it.

Answer (score 1):

The key is your 2nd question. As long as you're not whitelabeled, the receiving server 'knows' the mail came from SendGrid, so it checks SendGrid for all DKIM & SPF records. SendGrid signs your mail with their own DKIM if you're not whitelabeled, so it all checks through.

"Alternating" the domain does not sound like a feasible way to avoid bulking of your mail. We're still in an IPv4 world, and IPs are still the main source of reputation tracking in the email world. No matter what domain your mail says it's "From", the receiving server knows what IPs gave it the mail (unless your domain is so bad it's blacklisted).

What does [mail-tester.com](http://mail-tester.com) say about your mail?

Comment: After doing more research I think it has more to do with the fact that sendgrid uses a shared IP for the free plans than it has to do with domain reputation. I've run our mail through various testers and they've all been fine. So it seems like the best thing to do would be to upgrade so we could have a dedicated IP and not have our reputation linked with random other people.